# VBA code in a template

Tags: vba, templates, ms-word

In a Word template I have a command button with VBA code behind it.

The problem is that the code gets lost when a document is created using that template. The button is still visible, but the VBA code behind it disappears for some reason. This causes the button just to be clickable without performing any action.

The documents are saved in .docx format.

How can I 'glue' the button to its code so it doesn't get lost ?

Comment: In what format are the template and the documents saved? Anything saved in .dotx or .docx format will, by definition, lose all VBA code.

Comment: The templates are saved in a .dotm format. So normally they should keep the VBA code. After some testing, i think the command button can not be used for this problem. I tried an implementation with a field calling the macro stored in the normal.dot now. I will test this more today and report eventual findings later on.

Comment: ... yes, and in what format are the documents saved? .docx or .docm?

Comment: The documents are saved as docx. But this doenst matter, as the document is just used for the macro. This macro starts a program with a parameter depending on the case which they are working on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, make sure your VBA code is saved in the .dotm template that you make available to everyone (and not in your personal normal.dot/dotm template — this is only available on your machine).

Then, make sure the documents generated from the template are saved as **.docm** (not .docx).

.docx documents cannot contain VBA code. Anything saved in .dotx or .docx format will, by definition, lose all VBA code.

In a comment you say

> "this doenst matter, as the document is just used for the macro."

This is incorrect; it does very much matter. .docx documents can't "be used for" macros because they can't contain macros.

Comment: But when my template is saved as a .docm and afterwards used to generate a .doc document on my pc, the macro is still working. The problem is that the macro's dont get transferred together with the the template. Although i save the macro in the normal.dot

Comment: Now i understand what you mean. Your answer will probably be the solution to my question. I know that the explanation is a bit weak, but the problem aint that simple. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score -1):

For the macro to be always available, you need to store the macro in the normal template.

For example when recording a macro, select All Documents (Normal.dot) on Store Macro in.

Comment: But can i store the code from a command button there too? 
Because of simplicity reasons, the client should just press the button and the code should start running automatically.

Comment: Yes you can store in the users normal template. So when they open word the button is always there.

Comment: This doesn't really address this particular question. Macros stored in a .dotm template do propagate to the .docm documents generated from that template.